# Create a Factory Method Based on Parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I am a Learner in angularJs.
Today I read a difference between factory and service method in 'Novice to Ninja' of angular JS.

The statement is -

**"Note that you return an object from the factory function, so you have the freedom to determine which object to return based on certain parameters. This is not the case with services where you simply pass a constructor function to service()."**

So can anybody help me while creating such example in which I can return a customized object based on parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to add providers

```
var app  = app.moudule("app", []);

app.provider('customeFactory', function(){

   var type;
   return {

    setType: function(value){
      type = value;

    }, 

    $get: function (){
        if (type == "typeA"){
        return {
            type: 'TypeA was set:' + type;
        }
        }else {
           return {
            value: 'another type was set:' + type;
          }
        }


    }

   }

})


app.config(function(customeFactoryProvider){
    customeFactoryProvider.setType("typeA");
})
```

It means in abstract way

`factory` returns object which you have to customize it as you want as it describe revealing module pattern

```
var factoryFunc = function(){
  var saveFunc = function(){ /* logic */ }
  var updateFunc= function(){/* logic */ }
  // this function not exposed since it not specified in the return object 
  var deleteFunc = function(){ /* */ }
  var obj = {
      save: saveFunc,
      update: updateFunc
  }
  return obj;
}

// result now is the returned object {save, update}
var result = factoryFunc();
```

where the case in `service` is return the instance

```
var ServiceFunc = function () {
   this.funcA = function() {}
   this.funcB = function() {}
}
// result now is instance of ServiceFunc with all its functions A and B
var result = new ServiceFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got your point but needs some more info that as mentioned in statement (statement in Question) that we get the customized object based on "certain parameters". So just want to know that how can I pass the parameters and get customized object based on parameter.

Comment: Means based on parameter I will get object that contains only "save" functionality and based on other parameter returned object contains "all three functionality like save update and delete".

Comment: what I think of that Angular is responsible for instantiating `factory` and `service`  and inject them when it needed and each provider has its own way to instance it with `factory` it is only execute it as function `factory()` and `service ` as construct function `new service()`

Comment: Use `provider` to get more power of configure the object is returned

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. I got your point. I actually  want to know how can i create a return a customized object from factory based on parameters as  I read in Novice to Ninja book. Still I am not getting my answer. :(